# Are questions about German media (for language-learning by non-native speakers) on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic

I did not find any tags for topics relating to the **German media** (as a source of material for non-native learners of German).  (*Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.*)

This makes me uncertain as to whether the following are on-topic in German Language SE:

1. questions about German media suitable as vehicles for language-learning
2. questions about the use of German media websites/online resources

Answer (score 4):

We do have a list of resources for learners of German including media here:

[Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

It is a community wiki, i.e. everybody can add or suggest to add any resource they find interesting.